# How i configure redux store in component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i have react app that have own redux store I install react-planner to that application and follow the usage code in my react component but unfortunately its not working as throwing error that store is not defined.If anyone have proper doc to use react-planner then please share.Thanx!
i tried that :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Map } from "immutable";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import MyCatalog from './catalog/mycatalog';

import {
  Models as PlannerModels,
  reducer as PlannerReducer,
  ReactPlanner,
  Plugins as PlannerPlugins,
} from "react-planner";

//define state
let AppState = Map({
  "react-planner": new PlannerModels.State(),
});

//define reducer
let reducer = (state, action) => {
  state = state || AppState;
  state = state.update("react-planner", (plannerState) =>
    PlannerReducer(plannerState, action)
  );
  return state;
};

let store = createStore(reducer, (f) => f);

let plugins = [
  PlannerPlugins.Keyboard(),
  PlannerPlugins.Autosave("react-planner_v0"),
  PlannerPlugins.ConsoleDebugger(),
];

function WarehouseEditor() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactPlanner
        catalog={MyCatalog}
        width={800}
        store={store}
        height={600}
        plugins={plugins}
        stateExtractor={(state) => state.get("react-planner")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default WarehouseEditor;
```

Comment: did you try wrapping your ReactPlanner with Provider Component that you import from react-redux and give it the store as a prop?

Comment: yes i also tried that but returns 
Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(ReactPlanner)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(ReactPlanner)".

Comment: Could you post the code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Map } from "immutable";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import MyCatalog from './catalog/mycatalog';

import {
  Models as PlannerModels,
  reducer as PlannerReducer,
  ReactPlanner,
  Plugins as PlannerPlugins,
} from "react-planner";

//define state
let AppState = Map({
  "react-planner": new PlannerModels.State(),
});

//define reducer
let reducer = (state, action) => {
  state = state || AppState;
  state = state.update("react-planner", (plannerState) =>
    PlannerReducer(plannerState, action)
  );
  return state;
};

let store = createStore(reducer, (f) => f);

let plugins = [
  PlannerPlugins.Keyboard(),
  PlannerPlugins.Autosave("react-planner_v0"),
  PlannerPlugins.ConsoleDebugger(),
];

function WarehouseEditor() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ReactPlanner
        catalog={MyCatalog}
        width={800}
        height={600}
        plugins={plugins}
        stateExtractor={(state) => state.get("react-planner")}
      />
    </Provider>
  );
}
export default WarehouseEditor;
```

Comment: that's I tried with the provider